# Invalid column name when where condition while using case in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
   sdate,
   SUM(case when CGrp!='TOWNSHIP' and cdcode=0 and SDate between '4/1/2013' and '4/1/2013' then BillAmt end) as bill,
   sum(case  when CGrp!='TOWNSHIP' and cdcode!=0 and SDate between '4/1/2013' and '4/1/2013' then BillAmt end) as Net
from Indent
where bill != null     
group by SDate
```

The error message points to the line with `bill != null`

Comment: Apart from the syntax error (see mhasan's answer): You can't use `!=` (or the standard operator `<>`) for NULL values. You have to use `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Which dbms are you using? SQL Server? What is the actual error message you get (the one in the title looks weird...)?

Comment: Am using sql server .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use subquery to access alias name in select list .
The alias used in Select list  bill , Net are not accessible in WHERE clause .

```
select sdate,bill,Net from
(
select sdate, 
SUM(case when CGrp!='TOWNSHIP' and cdcode=0 and SDate between '4/1/2013' and '4/1/2013' then BillAmt end)as bill, 
SUM(case when CGrp!='TOWNSHIP' and cdcode!=0 and SDate between '4/1/2013' and '4/1/2013' then BillAmt end)as Net 
from Indent  group by SDate
)z
WHERE z.bill IS NOT NULL
```

This is because in sequence of query execution , WHERE clause is executed first and then SELECT .

General sequence of query execution.

```
1 . FROM
2 . WHERE
3 . GROUP BY
4 . SELECT
5 . ORDER BY
```

In your query's WHERE clause , you are using alias name `bill` but since this alias is defined later in SELECT , invalid column error is thrown .

Also for NULL comparison use `IS / IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for `something != NULL` would be `something IS NOT NULL`